ASP.NET Core Identity is logging me out
I have a website that has been working for a while. Once I log in, it keeps me logged in for several weeks.
However, I've just moved my site to a new server. And now, every time I'm away from the computer for hours, I have to log in again.
Does anyone know what could cause this?
Below is my configuration code.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/ErrorCode", "?code={0}");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    if (IsDemoSite)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }
    else
    {
        RewriteOptions options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()
            .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent();
        app.UseRewriter(options);
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers(); // For Railtrax API
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}


what is your auth/login? need some details here

@DanielA.White: I don't know what you're asking for. This is straight out of the box ASP.NET Core Identity.

Could you please tell me how you host this application? Inside the IIS or else? Is there any proxy which contains the rewrite rule ? Besides, what's the expire time now inside the F12 network?

The application is run using IIS. The code above shows how I set up the rewrite rules. So I do not believe that involves any proxy. I think it's within .NET. I don't know what is the F12 network. Logins seem to expire in about an hour.

I mean the browser's develop tool which you could open it by using F12 and inside this tool you could click the application tab and it contains the cookie which you could see the expire time for the login cookie.
